# JQuery Datepicker Only For Month and Year

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using jquery Datepicker UI .I need to display only month and year using this UI.
I Got that using the following code:

```
$(function() {
         $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm',
        onChangeMonthYear: function(dateText, inst) { 
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));

        }
    });
});
```

HTML :

```
<input type='text' id='date' name='eattdate' class='date-picker' value='".$date."' style='width:105px;'>
```

This works fine and It displays current month and year as default.But i want to make the month and year selected .

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, I believe you are missing the hiding of the calendar (and I guess you want that, as you only deal with months and years, but I may be wrong). So, if this is indeed you intention, use:

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
}
```

In your CSS file.

Now, as for the datepicker not opening in the previously selected date, you can introduce a `beforeShow`, as follows:

```
$(function() {
     $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm',

        onChangeMonthYear: function(dateText, inst) { 
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();

            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        },

        beforeShow: function() {
            var dateText = $(this).val();
            var isPopulated = dateText.length > 0;

            if (isPopulated) {
                var selectedDate = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", dateText + "-01");

                $(this).datepicker("option", "defaultDate", selectedDate);
                $(this).datepicker("setDate", selectedDate);
                $(this).datepicker("refresh");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I believe this should get you what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
defaultDate: new Date()
```